# Why is it impossible to compare a String and null with equals?

Tags: java

In the getter of my class the attribute may have null value from database :

```
public String getCible() {
    return cible.equals(null) ? " - " : cible;
}
```

In my code I want to call this getter , but I got NullPointerException.

If I change the comparison to `return cible == null ? " - " : cible;` then everything is wright :) So why ?

Comment: It is not impossible to compare a `string` with `null`. The point is it is impossible to call a method on a `null` value

Comment: equals and == are two different things. see full explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java
You can use org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.equals(cible, null) or of its a string then org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.equals(cible, null) which is null safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call a method on a `null`, so it is like `null.equals(null)`, `null` has no methods so it throws the exception.

If you dont want to use `==`, you can use `Objects.equals(yourString, null)`